# Linear bijection between a known and suspected vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

I have a finite-dimensional real vector space, $V$, and I have written a transformation $T:V\rightarrow W$ that I have confirmed is linear and bijective.

If I knew $W$ to be a vector space, I would conclude $V\cong W$. Alas, I do not know $W$ to be a vector space.

Does the existence of this “would-be” isomorphism $T$ guarantee that $W$ is a vector space? That is, does the existence of this $T$ guarantee that $W$ satisfies the vector space axioms for its definitions of vector addition and scalar multiplication?

Comment: What does it mean for $T : V \to W$ to be "linear" if $W$ is not a vector space?

Comment: $T(ax+by)=aT(x)+bT(y)$ @TravisWillse

Comment: Ah, so $W$ is already equipped with addition and scalar multiplication operations. Is your question then, How do we know that endowing $W$ with those operations makes $W$ a vector space?

Comment: If you don't know if $W$ is a vector space or not, what does $aT(x)+bT(y)$ means?

Comment: @TravisWillse Yes, I think that’s a fair way of describing my question. // You commented at almost the same time I submitted an edit. I think the edit aligns with your deciphering of my question.

Comment: @jjagmath I have definitions of vector addition and scalar multiplication in $W$, just not proof that the usual vector space axioms all hold.

Comment: @jjagmath So you can view ‘$+$’ as a binary operation, not necessarily commutative and associative, and so on.

Comment: @Asigan That’s my fear: that the existence of this “would be” isomorphism $T$ doesn’t count if there is a way for the addition and multiplication operations to fail the usual vector space axioms.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes.

Let

- $(V, +, \,\cdot\,)$ be a vector space over $\Bbb F$,
- $W$ a set equipped with operations

  - $\oplus: W \times W \to W$ and
  - $\odot: \Bbb F \times W \to W$, and
- $T : V \to W$ a bijection satisfying
  $$T(a \cdot x + b \cdot y) = (a \odot T(x)) \oplus (b \odot T(y))$$ for all $x, y \in V$ and scalars $a, b$ in the field $\Bbb F$ underlying $V$.

We can check each vector space axiom on $W$ directly. For example, the multiplication axiom asks that $a \odot (b \odot w) = (ab) \odot w$ for all $a, b \in \Bbb F$ and $w \in W$. Specializing the above identity to $a = 0$, $y = T^{-1}(w)$ gives $$b \odot w = b \odot T(T^{-1}(w)) = T(b \cdot T^{-1}(w)),$$ so
\begin{align}
a \odot (b \odot w)
&= T(a \cdot T^{-1}(T(b \cdot T^{-1}(w))))\\
&= T(a \cdot (b \cdot T^{-1}(w)))\\
&= T((a b) \cdot T^{-1}(w))\\
&= (ab) \odot T(T^{-1}(w))\\
&= (ab) \odot w ,
\end{align}
as desired. Notice that the third equality just follows from the fact that $(V, +, \,\cdot\,)$ itself satisfies the multiplication axiom, i.e., that $a \cdot (b \cdot y) = (a b) \cdot y$.

More generally, for any vector space $(V, +, \cdot)$ and any set $W$, any bijection $T : V \to W$ determines a vector space structure $(\oplus, \odot)$ on $W$ by rigging the operations $\oplus, \odot$ exactly so that $T$ is an isomorphism. Rearranging the definition of vector space isomorphism gives that these operations must be
\begin{align*}
w \oplus w' &:= T(T^{-1}(w) + T^{-1}(w')) \\
\lambda \odot w\phantom{'} &:= T(\lambda \cdot T^{-1}(w)) .
\end{align*}
This maneuver is sometimes called *transferring the structure* from $V$ to $W$ (via $T$); checking that $(W, \oplus, \odot)$ so defined is a vector space is just a matter of unwinding definitions.

Comment: Awesome! This is almost what I was hoping to see! My remaining concern is closure under $\oplus$ and $\odot$. Why do those come along for the ride?

Comment: Look at $w\oplus w' := T(T^{-1}(w) + T^{-1}(w'))$ in Travis' post, for example. We know that $w, w' \in W$ and so $T^{-1}(w), T^{-1}(w') \in V$. Thus their sum $T^{-1}(w) + T^{-1}(w')$ is in $V$ since $V$ is closed under its addition operation. Since $T$ maps from $V$ to $W$, define $v := T^{-1}(w) + T^{-1}(w')$ and we see that $T(v)\in W$, hence $W$ is closed under this operation. I think you can deduce closure under scalar multiplication similarly.

Comment: Right---put another way, taking $a = b = 1$ in the "linearity" identity satisfied by $T$ gives $T(x) \oplus T(y) = T(x + y)$, and taking $x = T^{-1}(w), y = T^{-1}(w')$ gives the formula for $w \oplus w'$. Scalar multiplication can be similarly handled by taking $b = 0$.